# Migrating only specific database items in Wordpress from staging to live

Tags: database, wordpress, staging

I want to find a way to push only certain pieces of my database from the staging environment to production. For instance, if I make a change in Widgets, but there’s changes in Pages I don’t want pushed yet, I can just push only Widgets without pushing the entire site.

Is there a plugin I can do this with? Or even any manual options.

Thanks

Comment: Have not used this plugin yet but I think they do what your looking for: https://wpstagecoach.com/. It is a paid plugin though.  Only other way I know of is to write your own migration scripts.

Comment: You might be able to use https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/ along with your own scripts to make this happen.